# How to write "top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;" with one property definition?

Tags: html, css

This is purely for convenience.

For the margin property we can condense `margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px;` as `margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;` and further as `margin:0px;`

Can we do the same for `top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;`? e.g., `placement:0;`?